# Navigate up with relative url

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I am trying to navigate up one level but cant quite get it to work right. Here's an example:

current url:

```
http://localhost/#/tinker/subdir/page1
```

I would like to be able to go to do something like this:

```
$location.url("../page2")
```

to end up here:

```
http://localhost/#/tinker/subdir/page2
```

It also might be important to note that I am using ui-router. When I do `$location.url("../page2");` from the first page, I end up with a url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/#/../page2
```

I'm sure there's got to be an easy way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Any Ideas?

Comment: $location.url  or  $location.href ???

Comment: I cant see that $location has an href

Answer (score 1):

If your current location is

```
http://localhost/#/tinker/page1
```

then you're already at the webroot folder, as the hashmark (`#`) is a local reference. So the current directory is

```
http://localhost/
```

and the browser should look for a local anchor named

```
/tinker/pages
```

or maybe jQuery is supposed to work with that.

This is just for your understanding of the situation, the `#/tinker/page1' is not a server request, the server page is simply "/".

Comment: I updated the example, what about that? The reason I'm trying to solve this is because I might not know the exact directory I want to go because it could change, but I do know relatively where I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UI Router, you don't navigate with URLs, you navigate with states. You can navigate to a parent state with `$state.go('^')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your webserver at the root of the project then instead of "../page2", you can try "/subdir/page2" and it should work. It's best practice to give relative path from the projects root dir instead of ".." as it improves readability.

Comment: The problem is my paths are subject to change based on the app which is including these "modules". I only know they wont change relatively.